# How to smooth the contour using Python

Tags: python, opencv, curve, smoothing

I am working on a detection problem and I have found the mask of the object using cv2.findContours(). However, the found contour has a lot of noise and isn't smooth while the requirement is that it has to be smooth so we can use that smooth contour for our next step.
[The obtained mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h27b.png)
[The curve I want (the red line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nspVn.png)

I have tried cv2.approxPolyDP() to reduce the noise but it is no longer a curve. I was asked to find a smooth curve.
[The curve after using cv2.approxPolyDP()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQl8X.png)

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: why dont you just filter (Smoothing filters) you image ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar When I use small kernels it helps a little but not much, there are still a lot of noises, but if I use a big one it becomes so blurry that I missed several parts of the contours before I can reach the ideal curve. Maybe I was doing it wrong? I am new to these.

Comment: you can do dilation then ..and then filtering ...edge detection .. and then finally contour detection .. have you tried everything ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar edge detection is where I miss some part of the contour but if I use cv2.findContours() again it works quite well then. Guess I was just overcomplicating things. Thanks for your help.